# Windows Time Sync issues cmd.exe & svchost running

Tags: windows, command-line, sync, time, utc

I have a strange issue that is happening with our time syncing error for a computer at work.

Randomly the PC changes time to a year,few minutes, hours back. Example: before the glitch it will be 06SEP21 09:05 and after the glitch 06SEP20 07:43.
It looks like the incorrect time sync is running through cmd.exe while the correct one runs svchost.exe. You can also see the incorrect time sync has a security ID while the other is a Local Service. It appears that we have competing time syncs happening on this system. The cmd.exe time sync is happening from the userID: S-1-5-----------. I would think an incorrect time sync was setup from a user profile

We setup task scheduler to run a good time sync every five minutes to sync the machine to ensure it would be the correct time, but once the cmd.exe time sync would happen it would break.

I'm not certain where this cmd.exe time sync is happening at.. I've attached a picture of the windows logs of the wrong time sync and a good time sync to show.

We have checked the CMOS battery and it's reporting "OK". We did not replace this yet. The system has been scanned for viruses and the disk repair was run.

[Time sync issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49sc4.png)

Any ideas of what to look at? Is the CMD.EXE a RTC time sync and not a UTC time sync? not sure how to check that.

Thank you